# Is __syncthreads() working properly in this code?

Tags: cuda, synchronization

---

EDIT:

Added more log info and push and pop related functions.

---

Setup: Geforce GT520, Windows 64 bits (compiling for 32 bits), Cuda 4.2.

In my code snippet I have work deques that feed threads with work. Each block has its own deque and can push or pop dynamic generated work items on its bottom (popWork and pushWork functions). popWork() can also steal work from other deques If the number of work items in its own deque is less than a threshold.

```
template <class TreeNode, class BV , int iDequeSize , int iFrontSize>
__global__ void traverseTree(const TreeNode* tree_object1, const GPUVertex* vertex_object1, const uint3* tri_object1,
int2* aBvttDeques, int* aiBvttBottoms, unsigned int* auiBvttAges, int *aiBvttDequeFlags , int *piOverflowFlag , 
int2* outputList, unsigned int* outputListIdx , int2* aFrontDeques , int *auiFrontBottoms)
{   
int iTid = threadIdx.x;
int iBid = blockIdx.x;

__shared__ int2 aLocalBvtt[BVTT_DEQUE_SHARED_SIZE];
__shared__ int2 aLocalFront[FRONT_DEQUE_SHARED_SIZE];
__shared__ int iLocalBvttCounter[WORK_STEALING_THREADS];
__shared__ int iLocalFrontCounter[WORK_STEALING_THREADS];
__shared__ unsigned int uiPopDequeIdx;
__shared__ int2 pushOrPopStartIdxAndSize;
__shared__ bool bPopOrPushFlag;
__shared__ unsigned int uiActiveDeques[NDEQUES]; //Contains indices for deques with useful work that can be stolen
__shared__ unsigned int uiActiveDequesIdx;

//Debug
int iRun = 0;
//

while(/*true*/ /*Debug*/iRun++ < 10) //Work loop will continue until cannot pop from bottom or cannot steal work from other deques
{
    //Debug
    if(iBid == 0 && (iTid == 0 || iTid == WORK_STEALING_THREADS - 1))
    {
        printf("(%d,%d) before sync0\n" , iBid , iTid);
    }

    __syncthreads();

    if(iBid == 0 && (iTid == 0 || iTid == WORK_STEALING_THREADS - 1))
    {
        printf("(%d,%d) after sync0\n" , iBid , iTid);
    }
    //

    int2 aWork_items[3];
    int2 aFront_item;
    int iBvttCount = 0;
    int iFrontCount = 0;

    if(!popWork<int2 , iDequeSize>(aiBvttDequeFlags , aiBvttBottoms , auiBvttAges , aBvttDeques , iTid , iBid ,
        uiPopDequeIdx , pushOrPopStartIdxAndSize , /*iLocalBvttCounter , iLocalFrontCounter ,*/ bPopOrPushFlag ,
        uiActiveDeques , uiActiveDequesIdx , aWork_items[0]))
    {   //No more work

        //Debug
        if(iTid == 0)
        {
            printf("(%d,%d)no work\n" , iBid , iTid);
        }
        //

        return; 
    }

    //Debug
    if(iTid == 0 && iBid == 0)
    {
        printf("(%d,%d) run=%d work=(%d,%d)\n" , iBid , iTid , iRun , aWork_items[0].x , aWork_items[0].y);
    }
    //

    if(iTid < pushOrPopStartIdxAndSize.y)
    {
        TreeNode node1      = tree_object1[aWork_items[0].x];
        TreeNode node2      = tree_object1[aWork_items[0].y];

        if(aWork_items[0].x == aWork_items[0].y)
        {   //intra-collision test (self collision)
            intraCollision<TreeNode , BV>(iBvttCount , aWork_items , aWork_items[0] , node1 , tree_object1);
        }
        else
        {   //inter-collision test
            //interCollision<TreeNode , BV>(iLocalBvttCounter , aLocalBvtt , outputList , outputListIdx , work_item ,
            //  node1 , node2 , tree_object1 , tri_object1 , aFrontDeques , auiFrontBottoms[iBid]);

            interCollision<TreeNode , BV>(iBvttCount , aWork_items , outputList , outputListIdx , aWork_items[0] ,
                node1 , node2 , tree_object1 , tri_object1 , aFront_item , iFrontCount);
        }
        //__syncthreads();
    }
    iLocalBvttCounter[iTid] = iBvttCount;
    iLocalFrontCounter[iTid] = iFrontCount;

    //Debug
    if(iBid == 0 && (iTid == 0 || iTid == WORK_STEALING_THREADS - 1))
    {
        printf("(%d,%d) before sync1\n" , iBid , iTid);
    }
    //

    __syncthreads();

    //Debug
    if(iBid == 0 && (iTid == 0 || iTid == WORK_STEALING_THREADS - 1))
    {
        printf("(%d,%d) after sync1\n" , iBid , iTid);
    }
    //

    {
        int iPrefixSum = prefixSum<WORK_STEALING_THREADS>(iLocalFrontCounter , iTid , iFrontCount);
        if(iFrontCount)
        {
            aLocalFront[iPrefixSum] = aFront_item;
        }
        if(iTid == WORK_STEALING_THREADS - 1)
        {
            iLocalFrontCounter[iTid] = iPrefixSum + iFrontCount;
        }

        iPrefixSum = prefixSum<WORK_STEALING_THREADS>(iLocalBvttCounter , iTid , iBvttCount);

        //Debug
        if(iTid == 0 && iBid == 0)
        {
            printf("(%d,%d) nChildren=%d prefixSum=%d\n" , iBid , iTid , iBvttCount , iPrefixSum);
            for(int i = 0 ; i < iBvttCount ; ++i)
            {
                printf("(%d,%d) children %d=(%d,%d)\n" , iBid , iTid , i , aWork_items[i].x , aWork_items[i].y);
            }
        }
        if(iTid == 1 && iBid == 0)
        {
            printf("(%d,%d) nprefixSumt2=%d\n" , iBid , iTid , iPrefixSum);
        }
        //

        for(int i = 0 ; i < iBvttCount ; ++i)
        {
            aLocalBvtt[iPrefixSum + i] = aWork_items[i];
        }
        if(iTid == WORK_STEALING_THREADS - 1)
        {
            iLocalBvttCounter[iTid] = iPrefixSum + iBvttCount;

            //Debug
            if(iBid == 0)
            {
                printf("(%d,%d) totalWork=%d, prefix=%d + count=%d\n" , iBid , iTid , iLocalBvttCounter[iTid] , iPrefixSum , iBvttCount);
            }
            //
        }
    }

    //Debug
    if(iBid == 0 && (iTid == 0 || iTid == WORK_STEALING_THREADS - 1))
    {
        printf("(%d,%d) before sync2\n" , iBid , iTid);
    }
    //

    __syncthreads();

    //Debug
    if(iBid == 0 && (iTid == 0 || iTid == WORK_STEALING_THREADS - 1))
    {
        printf("(%d,%d) after sync2\n" , iBid , iTid);
    }
    //

    //TODO: push work back only when memory size is good for better coallescence
    //Push back front to global mem
    if(!pushWork<int2 , iFrontSize>(auiFrontBottoms , aFrontDeques , iTid , iBid ,
        iLocalFrontCounter[WORK_STEALING_THREADS - 1] , aLocalFront , bPopOrPushFlag , pushOrPopStartIdxAndSize))
    {   //overflow
        if(iTid == 0)
        {
            //Debug
            printf("(%d,%d) front overflow\n" , iBid , iTid);
            //
            *piOverflowFlag = 1;
            atomicExch(&aiBvttDequeFlags[iBid] , 0);
        }
        return;
    }

    //Debug
    if(iTid == 0 && iBid == 0)
    {
        printf("(%d,%d) localnWork=%d\n" , iBid , iTid , iLocalBvttCounter[WORK_STEALING_THREADS - 1]);
    }
    //

    //Push back BVTT nodes to global mem
    if(!pushWork<int2 , iDequeSize>(aiBvttBottoms , aBvttDeques , iTid , iBid , iLocalBvttCounter[WORK_STEALING_THREADS - 1] ,
        aLocalBvtt , bPopOrPushFlag , pushOrPopStartIdxAndSize))
    {   //overflow
        if(iTid == 0)
        {
            //Debug
            printf("(%d,%d) bvtt overflow\n" , iBid , iTid);
            //

            *piOverflowFlag = 1;
            atomicExch(&aiBvttDequeFlags[iBid] , 0);
        }
        return;
    }

    //Debug
    if(iTid == 0 && iBid == 0)
    {
        printf("(%d,%d) bot=%d\n\n" , iBid , iTid , aiBvttBottoms[iBid]);
    }
    //

    //Debug
    if(iBid == 0 && (iTid == 0 || iTid == WORK_STEALING_THREADS - 1))
    {
        printf("(%d,%d) before sync4\n" , iBid , iTid);
    }

    __syncthreads();

    if(iBid == 0 && (iTid == 0 || iTid == WORK_STEALING_THREADS - 1))
    {
        printf("(%d,%d) after sync4\n" , iBid , iTid);
    }
    //
}

//Debug
if(iTid == 0)
{
    printf("(%d,%d) max iter\n" , iBid , iTid);
}
//
}
```

popWork() related code:

```
bool __inline__ __device__ popTop(int *aiDequesBottoms , unsigned int *auiDequesAges , const int &iBid ,
int2 &popStartIdxAndSize)
{
int index;
unsigned int oldAge = auiDequesAges[iBid];
int localBot = aiDequesBottoms[iBid];
index = oldAge >> WORK_STEALING_TAG_NBITS;
if(localBot < index + WORK_STEALING_POP_SIZE + WORK_STEALING_PUSH_SIZE)
{
    return false;
}

int localTag = oldAge & WORK_STEALING_TAG_MASK;
int size = min(WORK_STEALING_POP_SIZE , localBot - index);
unsigned int newAge = (index+size << WORK_STEALING_TAG_NBITS)| localTag;

if(oldAge == atomicCAS(&auiDequesAges[iBid] , oldAge , newAge))
{
    popStartIdxAndSize.x = index;
    popStartIdxAndSize.y = size;
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
}

bool __inline__ __device__ popBottom(int *aiDequesBottoms , unsigned int *auiDequesAges , const int &iBid ,
int2 &popStartIdxAndSize)
{
int localBot = aiDequesBottoms[iBid];
if(localBot == 0)
{
    return false;
}

int index = localBot;
localBot = localBot - WORK_STEALING_POP_SIZE;
atomicExch(&aiDequesBottoms[iBid] , localBot);

unsigned int oldAge = auiDequesAges[iBid];
int oldAgeTop = int(oldAge >> WORK_STEALING_TAG_NBITS);
if(localBot > oldAgeTop)
{
    popStartIdxAndSize.y = WORK_STEALING_POP_SIZE;
    popStartIdxAndSize.x = index - WORK_STEALING_POP_SIZE;
    return true;
}

atomicExch(&aiDequesBottoms[iBid] , 0);
unsigned int newAge = ((oldAge & WORK_STEALING_TAG_MASK) + 1) % (WORK_STEALING_TAG_MASK + 1);
if(index > oldAgeTop)
{
    if(oldAge == atomicCAS(&auiDequesAges[iBid] , oldAge , newAge))
    {
        popStartIdxAndSize.y = index - oldAgeTop;
        popStartIdxAndSize.x = index - popStartIdxAndSize.y;
        return true;
    }
}

atomicExch(&auiDequesAges[iBid] , newAge);
return false;
}

template <typename Work , int iDequeSize>
bool __inline__ __device__ popWork(int *aiDequeFlags , int *aiDequesBottoms , unsigned int *auiDequesAges ,
const Work *aDeques , const int &iTid , const int &iBid , unsigned int &uiPopDequeIdx , int2 &popStartIdxAndSize ,
/*int &iLocalDequeCounter , int &iLocalFrontCounter ,*/ bool &bPopFlag , unsigned int *uiActiveDeques ,
unsigned int &uiActiveDequesIdx , Work &work)
{
if(iTid == 0)
{   //Try to pop from block deque
    //iLocalDequeCounter = 0;
    //iLocalFrontCounter = 0;

    bPopFlag = popBottom(aiDequesBottoms , auiDequesAges , iBid , popStartIdxAndSize);

    if(bPopFlag)
    {
        uiPopDequeIdx = iBid;
    }
    else
    {
        atomicExch(&aiDequeFlags[iBid] , 0);
    }
}
__syncthreads();

while(!bPopFlag)
{   //No more work, try to steal some (Help, police! We have a burglar here)!
    if(iTid == 0)
    {
        uiActiveDequesIdx = 0;

        //Debug
        /*if(iBid == 6 || iBid == 1)
        {
            printf("bid=%d dequeFlags:[%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d]\n" , iBid , aiDequeFlags[0] , aiDequeFlags[1] ,
                aiDequeFlags[2] , aiDequeFlags[3] , aiDequeFlags[4] , aiDequeFlags[5] , aiDequeFlags[6] ,
                aiDequeFlags[7]);

            printf("bId=%d dequesCounts:[%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d]\n" , iBid , aiDequesBottoms[0] ,
                aiDequesBottoms[1] , aiDequesBottoms[2] , aiDequesBottoms[3] , aiDequesBottoms[4] ,
                aiDequesBottoms[5] , aiDequesBottoms[6] , aiDequesBottoms[7]);
        }*/
        //
    }
    __syncthreads();

    if(iTid < NDEQUES)
    {
        if(aiDequeFlags[iTid] == 1) //assuming iTid >= NDEQUES
        {   //Set this deque for a work stealing atempt.
            unsigned int uiIdx = atomicAdd(&uiActiveDequesIdx,1);
            uiActiveDeques[uiIdx] = iTid;
        }
    }
    __syncthreads();

    if(iTid == 0)
    {   //Try to steal until succeeds or there are no more deques left to search
        bPopFlag = false;
        for(uiPopDequeIdx = 0 ; uiPopDequeIdx < uiActiveDequesIdx; ++uiPopDequeIdx)
        {
            bPopFlag = popTop(aiDequesBottoms , auiDequesAges , uiPopDequeIdx , popStartIdxAndSize);
            if(bPopFlag)
            {
                atomicExch(&aiDequeFlags[iBid] , 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    __syncthreads();

    if(uiActiveDequesIdx == 0)
    { //No more work to steal. End.
        return false;
    }
    __syncthreads();
}

//Get poped data
if(iTid < popStartIdxAndSize.y) //assuming number of threads >= WORK_SIZE
{
    work = aDeques[uiPopDequeIdx*iDequeSize + popStartIdxAndSize.x + iTid];

    //Debug
    /*if(iTid == 20 && iBid == 0)
    {
        printf("work=(%d,%d) deque=%d dSize=%d start=%d final=%d\n" , work.x , work.y , uiPopDequeIdx , iDequeSize ,
            popStartIdxAndSize.x , uiPopDequeIdx*iDequeSize + popStartIdxAndSize.x + iTid);
    }*/
    //
}

return true;
}
```

pushWork() related code:

```
template<int iDequeSize>
bool __inline__ __device__ pushBottom(int *aiDequeBottoms , const int &iBid , int2 &pushStartIdxAndSize)    
{
int iOldBot = aiDequeBottoms[iBid];
pushStartIdxAndSize.x = iOldBot;
iOldBot += pushStartIdxAndSize.y;

if(iOldBot < iDequeSize)
{
    atomicExch(&aiDequeBottoms[iBid] , iOldBot);
    return true;
}

return false;
}


template <typename Work , int iDequeSize>
bool __inline__ __device__ pushWork(int *aiDequesBottoms , Work *aDeques , const int &iTid , const int &iBid ,
const unsigned int &uiDequeOutputCounter , Work *aOutputLocalWork , bool &bPushFlag , int2 &pushStartIdxAndSize)
{
if(uiDequeOutputCounter == 0)
{
    return true;
}

pushStartIdxAndSize.y = uiDequeOutputCounter;

if(iTid == 0)
{
    bPushFlag = pushBottom<iDequeSize>(aiDequesBottoms , iBid , pushStartIdxAndSize);
}

//Debug
if(iBid == 0 && (iTid == 0 || iTid == WORK_STEALING_THREADS - 1))
{
    printf("(%d,%d) before push sync\n" , iBid , iTid);
}
//
__syncthreads();

//Debug
if(iBid == 0 && (iTid == 0 || iTid == WORK_STEALING_THREADS - 1))
{
    printf("(%d,%d) after push sync\n" , iBid , iTid);
}
//

if(!bPushFlag)
{
    return false;
}

//Transfer to global mem.
//unsigned int uiWorkLeft = uiDequeOutputCounter;
unsigned int uiThreadOffset = iTid;

//Debug
//int iRun = 0;
//

while(uiThreadOffset < uiDequeOutputCounter)
{
    //Debug
    /*if(iTid == 0 && iBid == 0)
    {
        printf("workLeft=%d bot=%d\n" , uiWorkLeft , aiDequesBottoms[iBid]);
    }*/
    //
        //Debug
        /*if(iBid == 0)
        {
            printf("tid=%d run=%d pushStartIdx.x=%d final=%d\n" , iTid , iRun , pushStartIdxAndSize.x ,
                iDequeSize*iBid + pushStartIdxAndSize.x +  iTid);
        }*/
        //

        //aDeques[iDequeSize*iBid + pushStartIdxAndSize.x +  iTid] = aOutputLocalWork[uiThreadOffset];

    atomicExch(&(aDeques[iDequeSize*iBid + pushStartIdxAndSize.x + uiThreadOffset].x) , aOutputLocalWork[uiThreadOffset].x);
    atomicExch(&(aDeques[iDequeSize*iBid + pushStartIdxAndSize.x + uiThreadOffset].y) , aOutputLocalWork[uiThreadOffset].y);

    uiThreadOffset += blockDim.x;

    //Debug
    //++iRun;
    //

    //__threadfence();
}

return true;
}
```

My problem is that threads aren't seem to be waiting on sync points (__syncthreads()) after first iteration. This is stated by the generated log. Also this problem only happens on Release build. Debug build is working fine in this aspect.

```
(0,0) before sync0
(0,95) before sync0
(0,0) after sync0
(0,95) after sync0
(0,95) before sync1
(0,0) run=1 work=(0,0)
(0,0) before sync1
(0,0) after sync1
(0,95) after sync1
(0,0) nChildren=3 prefixSum=0
(0,95) totalWork=3, prefix=3 + count=0
(0,0) children 0=(1,2)
(0,95) before sync2
(0,0) children 1=(1,1)
(0,0) children 2=(2,2)
(0,1) nprefixSumt2=3
(0,0) before sync2
(0,0) after sync2
(0,95) after sync2
(0,0) localnWork=3
(0,95) before push sync
(0,0) before push sync
(0,0) after push sync
(0,95) after push sync
(0,95) before sync4
(0,95) after sync4 //PROBLEM HERE! (0,95) SHOULD STAY WAINTING IN SYNC4.
(0,0) bot=3

(0,0) before sync4
(0,95) before sync0 //NOW THREADS ARE SYNC ON DIFFERENT POINTS.
(0,0) after sync4
(0,95) after sync0
```

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Geforce GT520, Windows 64 bits (compiling for 32 bits), Cuda 4.2.

Comment: How about using another __syncthreads() at the begining of while?

Comment: Already tried that but no avail.

Answer (score 1):

The early `return` spoils uniformity here. Technically, from there on all `__syncthreads()` are within conditional code, and thus have undefined behavior. Note this is even true if it is never executed, as it still influences the compiler's choice of reconvergence points.

If some threads run out of work, you still have to keep them alive to cooperate in the `__syncthreads()`.

---

You can test this theory by eliminating the returns and instead setting a per-thread "skip code" flag. All code apart from the __syncthreads() should then be inside `if (!skip_flag) {...}` conditionals. I believe this would solve this issue (unless there are unrelated problems).

Alternatively you could dive into the object code using `cuobjdump -sass` and check the placement of reconvergence points by looking at the `SSY` instructions. I believe you'll find places where the synchronization point is past the next `__syncthreads()`, probably all the way down until the end of the kernel.

Comment: Is it the case even if popWork() flags out of work per block and not per thread? I'll post popWork() code so You can see how pop is done.

Comment: Added a more detailed log. Now I can see that thread (0,95) is bypassing sync point, but don't figured why yet.

Comment: Yes, I believe this is still the case if the conditional return is executed uniformly across the block, or even if it is never executed at all, because it changes the compiler's choice of reconvergence points. So the conditional code sections in the object code might extend further than in the source code (on compute capability 2.0 or higher probably all the way until the end of the kernel) and thus include the `__syncthreads()` which is supposed to be unconditional. I admit this probably violates the documented behavior, but I believe that is how it is.

Comment: It would be nice to hear a word on this from an Nvidia employee with a bit more inside knowledge. I believe this has always been a shady area and would like to dig out related posts from Nvidia's CUDA forums, but unfortunately they are still down.

Answer (score 0):

Just an observation: you have multiple synchronization points in your kernel.

Could it be that you have multiple __syncthreads() within your loop. The threads excute at different pace and they are synchronized at different synchronization points? Some are waiting at first sync point and some are at the next one. thus everything breaks down. synchronize at the end of the loop may solve this problem.

Comment: Adding a __syncthreads() on the ending of the loop doesn't have changed the results.